# É possível receber informações em tempo real do Chrome em Python?

Tags: python, http, proxy

Olá. Gostaria de saber se há como pegar informações da proxy que vem disponível por padrão no Google Chrome (a das ferramentas de desenvolvedores) a ponto que eu possa usa-las em tempo real em Python sem que eu necessite de usar WebDriver do Selenium, por exemplo.

Ex.: Faço uma requisição ao google.com, minha proxy recebe HTTP200 e automaticamente meu programa recebe a informação que eu consegui me conectar ao site e printa na tela do terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não há um "proxy embutido" no chrome. 
Se você está vendo um menu ou opções de proxy na sua interface de ferramentas para desenvolvedores do Chrome, é por que tem alguma extensão de proxy instalada no seu navegador.

O que o chrome tem é justamente uma API que permite que extensões definam configurações de proxy -

Então para fazer o que você quer, ou tem que usar um proxy "normal", externo - 
e programar esse proxy para imprimir as configurações desejadas, e configurar o chrome (pela extensão que você já tem, ou nas configurações do sistema operacional) pra usar esse proxy - ou criar uma extensão de proxy que faça requisições para um programa seu em Python no localhost, e passe as informações necessárias.

Para a opção 1, uma busca rápida revela que existem alguns projetos (tais como https://github.com/luugiathuy/WebProxyPython ) que são proxys simples, escritos em Python, que você vai poder adaptar para o que você quer fazer.